# Efficient way to track returning users?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm in the process of finding an efficient way to track returning users.

List of options I went over so far:

- save (update) login count per user, per day/week/month
- save (update) which users have logged in, in a Text field (bad choice?), per day/week/month
- deduce returning users via other database resources (user-added records from several tables)

I think this last option is most efficient, since I won't need to create a separate logging table.

However, a logging table seems more accurate, period-wise, right?

---

**Update:**

Accuracy still has the priority for this, so I went with the first option, together with some logic in PHP.

I've opted to store the **login counts per week** (of the year), like: `201433`.

Question: regarding the PHP code, is there a way to combine the two queries, and leave out the nested loop (efficiency)?

---

**Database Table:**

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id | userId | logins | year_week |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |      4 |    201432 |
|  2 |      1 |      3 |    201433 |
|  3 |      2 |      2 |    201433 |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

**Queries:**

```
SELECT
    userId,
    SUM(logins) as total
FROM
    User_Logins
GROUP BY
    userId
ORDER BY
    userId

-----------

// get first year_week

SELECT
    userId,
    year_week
FROM
    User_Logins
GROUP BY
    userId
ORDER BY
    userId
```

**Query results:**

```
+--------+-------+
| userId | total |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |     7 |
|      2 |     2 |
+--------+-------+

+--------+-----------+
| userId | year_week |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |    201432 |
|      2 |    201433 |
+--------+-----------+
```

**PHP code:**

```
$returningUsers = 0;

$userLogins = $this->model->firstQuery();
$userLoginWeeks = $this->model->secondQuery();


$today = new DateTime();


function weeksPassed($today, $year, $week)
{
    $today->setISODate($today->format('Y'), $today->format('W'));

    // year and week from user first login
    $yearWeek = new DateTime();
    $yearWeek->setISODate($year, $week);

    $daysPassed  = $today->diff($yearWeek)->days;
    $weeksPassed = $daysPassed / 7;

    return $weeksPassed;
}


if ($userLogins && $userLoginWeeks)
{
    foreach ($userLoginWeeks as $userLoginWeek)
    {
        $userId    = $userLoginWeek->userId;
        $year_week = $userLoginWeek->year_week;

        $year = (int) substr($year_week, 0, 4);
        $week = (int) substr($year_week, 4);

        $weeksPassed = weeksPassed($today, $year, $week);


        $totalLogins = 0;


        // Look up user logins from other query
        foreach ($userLogins as $logins)
        {
            if ($logins->userId == $userId)
            {
                $totalLogins = $logins->total;
                break;
            }
        }


        $avgLogins = $totalLogins;


        //  Average calculated over weeks that have passed since first login
        if ($weeksPassed > 0)
        {
            $avgLogins = $totalLogins / $weeksPassed;
        }


        // if average >= 1 per week  =>  returning user
        if ($avgLogins >= 1)
        {
            $returningUsers++;
        }
    }
}


return $returningUsers;
```

Comment: By recurring users, you mean returning ? Then your best choice IMHO is the first one. You can have # of logins, last_login, and even a frequency column based on an average per period.

Comment: I guess it depends on how robust of a solution you want, which in turn depends on how important this data is to your users/clients/employers. If you have the server capacity, and the need for the data, a log table that registers the userid, last_login_dt, browser_info, etc... this data could be used for statistics on user activity. Once a month you could run a script that parses the previous months data into more compact form to save you from having to do constant calculation when the older data might not need the level of granularity that newer data might.

Comment: @Charleshaa What do you mean by a frequency column? Isn't that what the day/week/month column is for? Login counts per user per day/week/month.

Comment: @gmiley `last_login` is already stored in the main `Users` table, so I won't be needing that anymore in a counting table. Additional info like browser_info isn't really needed.

Comment: @jlmmns the frequency column can be a sort of score for the returning users, the higher it is, the more the user is using the service. It can act as a helper for you to query for most returning without having to do complex queries. It was just an idea to make it easier. But it depends what you are going to use it for... If you really need the data to be split by period, then it's better to have a logging table. Or use a third party like [Intercom](http://intercom.io)

Comment: I've updated my question with an example for the first option. But I'm concerned about the efficiency of the nested loop.